# Selenium WebDriver and JavaScript change

Tags: javascript, webdriver

How on earth I get this Javascript method

```
$('#principal_uid').change(function() {
if($(this).val().length > 0){
 window.location.href = "/switch.html" + "?uid=" + $(this).val();
  } else {
  window.location.href = "/index.html";
```

To work with my Selenium WebDdriver test, where I try to change the field's value?
The problem is the field has a default value, but Selenium clear()-method does not clear it, although the test is passing.

I've tried something

```
 WebElement field =driver.findElement(By.id("principal_uid"));
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 js.executeScript("$('#principal_uid').change");
 field.clear();


field.sendKeys("newValue"+Keys.RETURN); //CHRASHED THE TEST WITH ERROR COMMUNICATING REMOTE SERVER ERROR
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't crash here `js.executeScript("$('#principal_uid').change");`? That code has an error.

Comment: Actually, that javascript is of completely valid syntax and will not raise any errors. It will not *do* anything and was definitely not intended, but is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
js.executeScript("$('#principal_uid').val('%s')".format("newValue"));
```

this should trigger the "onchange" event and redirect you to the page as described in the code.

if the event is not triggered (although it should be) you can add:

```
js.executeScript("$('#principal_uid').trigger('change')")
```

Comment: I would recommend using `triggerHandler()` as it is safer and more suited to this case. Reading [here](http://davidwalsh.name/dont-trigger-real-event-names).